# Code still executed after return statement in catch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
console.log('1');
await get()
    .then()
    .catch(() => {
        console.log('2');

        return;
    });
console.log('3');
```

Why did console logs 1 2 3? I thought after return statement, the code will be not executed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return` will only terminate the *current* function. Here, the function that gets terminated by the `return` is the `.catch` callback.

Since `.catch` returns a resolved Promise, the `await`ed Promise chain will resolve when the `catch` resolves.

If you want to stop the *outer* function when the `catch` runs, have your `catch` return something that you check outside, eg:

```js
(async() => {
  console.log('1');
  const result = await Promise.reject()
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('2');

      return 2;
    });
  if (result === 2) {
    return;
  }
  console.log('3');
})();
```

Or have the `.catch` throw an error, so that the outer Promise chain rejects. Since it's being `await`ed, the whole outer Promise will then reject:

```js
const fn = async () => {
  console.log('1');
  const result = await Promise.reject()
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('2');
      throw new Error();
    });
  console.log('3');
};

fn()
  .then(() => console.log('resolved'))
  .catch(() => console.log('rejected'))
```

If your `.catch` doesn't do anything substantial but you want this sort of behavior, it's usually a good idea to omit it entirely. That way, when there's an error, the `await`ed Promise will reject, the function will terminate, and the error can be caught by the appropriate consumer.

```js
const fn = async () => {
  console.log('1');
  const result = await Promise.reject();
  console.log('3');
};

fn()
  .then(() => console.log('resolved'))
  .catch(() => console.log('rejected'))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the return is in a separate function (the catch handler).

The return only applies to the function it is inside of. It will not affect the outer scope.